# Morphia and $sort operator

Tags: mongodb, morphia

I have a collection with documents like this:

```
book {
  title: "hello world",
  chapters: [
    {
      number: "2",
      title: "foo2"
    },{
      number: "1",
      title: "foo1"
    }
  ]
}
```

I need one of this options:

1. A query where the document gotten has the array of chapters sorted by chapter.number
2. A save operation where sort the array before push the document (but by delegation to mongodb)

I have seen **$sort** operation in official mongodb documentation but I don't know how use it in Morphia.
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/sort/

The output should be:

book {
      title: "hello world",
      chapters: [
        **{
          number: "1",
          title: "foo1"
        },
        {
          number: "2",
          title: "foo2"
        }**
      ]
    }

Answer (score 0):

you can't sort subdocuments like that.  You can sort your results, otherwise, as shown [here](https://github.com/mongodb/morphia/wiki/Query#sort).

Comment: I have already read morphia's wiki but what I need is sorting the subdocuments in the result query.

Comment: Which I said was impossible.  Karman Valenzuela's answer looks promising if you can take the hit of updating your documents.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Mongo $sort Manual](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/sort/) :

**Solution 1:**

if your collection is "book" you can try somewhere like that:

```
db.book.update( {title: "hello word"},
                { $push: {
                            chapters:{
                                        $each:[],
                                        $sort: {number:1}                                            
                                    }
                        }
                })
```

*Test:*

Create document:

```
db.book.insert({
    title: "hello world",
    chapters: [
        {
          number: "2",
          title: "foo2"
        },{
          number: "1",
          title: "foo1"
        }
    ]
})
```

Check:

```
db.book.find().pretty()
```

Sort chapters by number:

```
db.book.update( {title: "hello world"},
                { $push: {
                            chapters:{
                                        $each:[],
                                        $sort: {number:1}                                            
                                    }
                        }
                })
```

Check again:

```
db.book.find().pretty()
```

**Solution 2:**

Else if you really have any collection with the document "book" embedded, this is solution:

```
db.yourcollection.update( {"book.title": "hello world"},
            { $push: {
                        "book.chapters":{
                                    $each:[],
                                    $sort: {number:1}                                            
                                }
                    }
            })
```

*Test:*

Create document:

```
db.yourcollection.insert({book:{
    title: "hello world",
    chapters: [
      {
        number: "2",
        title: "foo2"
      },{
        number: "1",
        title: "foo1"
      }
    ]
}})
```

Check:

```
db.book.find().pretty()
```

Sort chapters by number:

```
db.yourcollection.update( {"book.title": "hello world"},
            { $push: {
                        "book.chapters":{
                                    $each:[],
                                    $sort: {number:1}                                            
                                }
                    }
            })
```

Check again:

```
db.book.find().pretty()
```

Comment: This is a good answer if not use Morphia. What I don't like so much is to have to run two queries (insertion and update) for sort an array. Anyway this should be fine if I might use it with Morphia.

Comment: Have reason, do not use Morphia but you can apply it in mongo console and really only would use "update", "insert" is only for this example. If you want apply sort for each documents in your collection could be made some like that: `db.yourcollection.find().forEach(<update code>)`.
[Mongo - cursor.forEach()](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.forEach/)